# Input form only accept some few chars

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

My problem is that i have a input form with a php code that insert into table. And later retrieving data from msql database. The issue is that in the input people can type in what they want en edit the page. They are acctuly only suppose to be able to insert a link but now they can make new divs.

So i want to make so they only can use character (http://EXAMPLE.com)

the code i use

```
<form action="updatehref.php" method="POST">

<textarea type="text" name="href" id="href">
Link here</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried?

Comment: I have treid pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_|]{6,25} and some javascript codes but didnt seem to work

Comment: Take a look at the [`strip_tags`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function, which lets you specify a list of allowable HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

The textarea element that you are using (and malformed BTW) is c pable of holding upto 65K of text. If you only want a URL, which is about 255 characters then use

```
<input type='text' name='href' id='href' value=''>
```

You will need to use JavaScript AND a server-side language (incase JavaScript is disabled) to test the validity of the input.

Comment: hm.. Okei, but they can still write <div> and mess up with my design, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: I fixed it by using this page: http://www.jasondahlin.com/2011/coding-tips/javascript-input-limiter.asp thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: Just be aware that you will also need to test the user inputs on the server-side as well.